# Rome XmlReader not reading https feed

Tags: java, rss, feed, rss-reader, rome

I am trying to read https://d3ca01230439ce08d4aab0c61810af23:bla@mycon.mycompany.com/recordings.atom

using Rome but its giving me error

```
   INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.AES$ECB.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
```

and

```
   Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://d3ca01230439ce08d4aab0c61810af23:bla@mycon.mycompany.com/recordings.atom .
```

I am doing this

```
    URL url =  new URL("https://d3ca01230439ce08d4aab0c61810af23:bla@mycon.mycompany.com/recordings.atom ");

    try {
    SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();

        SyndFeed feed = input.build(new XmlReader(url));

        System.out.println("Feed Author:"+feed.getAuthor());

        for(Object entries: feed.getEntries()){

            SyndEntry entry = (SyndEntry) entries;

            System.out.println("title :"+entry.getTitle());
            System.out.println("description : "+entry.getDescription());

        }


    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | FeedException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Do I need to put the username password somewhere?

**update**

This I have done

```
  URL url =  new URL("https://d3ca01230439ce08d4aab0c61810af23:bla@mycon.mycompany.com/recordings.atom");

    HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

    String encoding = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode("username:pass".getBytes());

    httpcon.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I hit that URL from my browser it asks for basic authentication. You can do this with ROME:

```
URL feedUrl = new URL(feed)
HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection)feedUrl.openConnection();
String encoding = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode("username:password".getBytes());
httpcon.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
SyndFeed feed = input.build(new XmlReader(httpcon));
```

You probably shouldn't use sun.misc.BASE64Encoder. Rather find another one somewhere.

From: http://cephas.net/blog/2005/02/09/retrieving-an-rss-feed-protected-by-basic-authentication-using-rome/

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your response I tried above but still I am getting Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://d3ca01230439ce08d4aab0c61810af23:bla@jemm.highrisehq.com/recordings.atom error. I didn't get you what do you mean by "probably shouldn't use sun.misc.BASE64Encoder"

Answer (score 0):

I find this a bit more elastic when it comes to authentication, this code works with and without authentication:

```
URL feedUrl = new URL("http://the.url.to/the/feed");
//URL feedUrl = new URL("http://user:pass@the.url.to/the/feed");

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) feedUrl.openConnection();
if (feedUrl.getUserInfo() != null) {
    String encoding = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(feedUrl.getUserInfo().getBytes());
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
}

SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
SyndFeed feed = input.build(new XmlReader(connection));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the following in place of

```
String encoding = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode("username:password".getBytes());
```

to this:

```
String BASIC_AUTH = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString("username:password".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
```