# Apache Camel RSS module with basic authentication

Tags: java, rss, apache-camel, basic-authentication

I am trying to use *Apache Camel's* [rss module](https://camel.apache.org/rss.html) to use an basic authentication protected RSS feed as *Endpoint*. However, I can't find any documentation **how to pass it the user credentials**. Does anybody know how to do this? Good workarounds are also appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible at the moment. camel-rss uses rome to read RSS Feeds.
Take a look to the code of `org.apache.camel.component.rss.RssUtils`:

```
public static SyndFeed createFeed(String feedUri, ClassLoader classLoader) throws Exception {
    ClassLoader tccl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    try {
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);
        InputStream in = new URL(feedUri).openStream();
        SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
        return input.build(new XmlReader(in));
    } finally {
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(tccl);
    }
}
```

To use basic authentication there must be something like

```
public static SyndFeed createFeed(String feedUri, ClassLoader classLoader) throws Exception {
    ClassLoader tccl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    try {
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);
        URL feedUrl = new URL(feedUri);
        HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection)feedUrl.openConnection();
        String encoding = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode("username:password".getBytes());
        httpcon.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
        SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
        return input.build(new XmlReader(httpcon));
    } finally {
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(tccl);
    }
}
```

This is the way described here --> [rome-xmlreader-not-reading-https-feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568576/rome-xmlreader-not-reading-https-feed)

I opened a new ticket for this feature. --> [CAMEL-9009](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9009)